# Type com.google.gson.ExclusionStrategy is defined multiple times

Tags: android, gradle, build, build.gradle, contentful

I'm getting this error when I try to add an implementation to my app's gradle file for [Contentful](https://www.contentful.com/developers/docs/android/tutorials/getting-started-with-contentful-and-android/)

```
Type com.google.gson.ExclusionStrategy is defined multiple times
```

It looks like something in my intermediate dex file is going on. Here's the full error:

```
Error: /Users/ceddings/StudioProjects/r15-android-rms-kiosk-launcher/kiosk/build/intermediates/mixed_scope_dex_archive/debug/out/2fcf9ca3ebe4bba6e5de15039706dbd823b837def40fd130c6d32dbf72d7d3fe_1.jar:classes.dex, Type com.google.gson.ExclusionStrategy is defined multiple times: /Users/ceddings/StudioProjects/r15-android-rms-kiosk-launcher/kiosk/build/intermediates/mixed_scope_dex_archive/debug/out/2fcf9ca3ebe4bba6e5de15039706dbd823b837def40fd130c6d32dbf72d7d3fe_1.jar:classes.dex, /Users/ceddings/StudioProjects/r15-android-rms-kiosk-launcher/kiosk/build/intermediates/mixed_scope_dex_archive/debug/out/1c3715710bef6d11c4bd58c73e056adcb809f2dac72c25d60ee538a9010444f0_1.jar:classes.dex
```

Below is my gradle file. How do I resolve this issue?

```
dependencies {
implementation project(':sharedcore')
implementation project(':data')
implementation project(':scanner')

implementation deps.kotlin.kotlin_jre
implementation deps.android.app_compat
implementation deps.android.material
implementation deps.android.constraint_layout
implementation deps.logging.timber
implementation deps.retrofit.retrofit
implementation deps.retrofit.retrofit_moshi
implementation deps.moshi.moshi
implementation deps.koin.koin_viewmodel
implementation deps.kotlin.coroutines_core
implementation deps.kotlin.coroutines_android
implementation(deps.auth.adal) {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'appcompat-v7'
    exclude group: 'com.google.code.gson', module: 'gson'
}
implementation deps.ms_app_center.analytics
implementation deps.ms_app_center.crashes
implementation deps.viewpager2.viewpager2
implementation deps.contentful.contentful

// Testing
testImplementation deps.testing.junit
testImplementation deps.testing.test_core
testImplementation deps.testing.test_runner
testImplementation deps.testing.test_rules
testImplementation deps.testing.ext_junit
testImplementation deps.testing.mockk
testImplementation deps.testing.mockk_android
testImplementation deps.testing.robolectric
testImplementation deps.testing.espresso_core
testImplementation deps.testing.espresso_intents
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
configurations {
    implementation.exclude module: 'gson' //Remove duplicate dependencies： gson
}
```

Answer (score 1):

All above answers did not work for me.

app/build.gradle
configurations{
all*.exclude module:'gson'  //Remove duplicate dependencies： gson
}

This will work.

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered the same problem, I guess you should delete "exclude group: 'com.google.code.gson', module: 'gson' in the build.gradle file, and look at the settings.gradle file in the project root directory similar And delete the file....

Answer (score 0):

Deleting the file at location corresponding to `C/Users/ceddings/StudioProjects/r15-android-rms-kiosk-launcher/kiosk/build/intermediates/mixed_scope_dex_archive/debug/out/1c3715710bef6d11c4bd58c73e056adcb809f2dac72c25d60ee538a9010444f0_1.jar:classes.dex` solved the issue for me.